# python markdown which version has a mark method

Tags: javascript, python, brython

When experimenting with the brython project, running "scripts/make_dist" always gets an error:

```
File "../scripts/make_dist.py", line 14, in <module>
 import make_doc  # lint:ok
File "/home/.../brython-3.1.1/scripts/make_doc.py", line 42, in <module>
 html, scripts = markdown.mark(src)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mark'
```

The problem is caused by [the file github.com/brython-dev/brython/scripts/make_doc.py](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/blob/master/scripts/make_doc.py).

While looking deeper, the "[Lib/browser/markdown.py](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/blob/master/www/src/Lib/browser/markdown.py)" or "[Lib/markdown2.py](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/blob/master/www/src/Lib/markdown2.py)" under its "www/src/" do contain a function "mark()" in each of them. Though those files are tailored for running inside a browser, cannot be used on a host/unix environment.

Which "markdown" version contains such a "mark()" function? Where are those brython markdown/markdown2 files derived from? How do you run "make_dist.py"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, but you might have a module "markdown" in your Python distribution. In this case, `import markdown` would import this module, not the one provided by Brython.

Just add `print(markdown)` after the line `import markdown` to check which module is imported.

I will change make_doc.py to make sure the correct module is imported.

Comment: I saw the change in repo. A quick try shows probably that's the right fix. Will confirm after more testing.